# Time Roundup issue in T-SQL with Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I want to accomplish a task that both Excel’s 75min roundup output and sql server’s 75min roundup output should be same result for the date time inputs. I used the following function in sql server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time DATETIME, @RoundToMin INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Time,121) AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) * (1440/@RoundToMin),0)/(1440/@RoundToMin)
END
GO
SELECT dbo.roundtime('11/2/2012  9:22:00',75)
```

The result I got for the above query is "**2012-11-02 08:51:00**"

The same scenario I applied in Excel `=MROUND (A1, TIME(0,75,0))" formula with same input('11/2/2012  9:22:00 AM')`

The Excel result is "**11/2/2012 8:45**"

I believe that the Excel result is correct and I want to achieve the same result in SQL server..

Are there any other ways to complete this task..

Comment: Hello Kavi, sorry I don't know T-SQL so I can't help you with the specific question but I'm interested to know what result you expect. In Excel at least the MROUND formula will give different times for the same time on different days because 75 mins doesn't divide exactly in to a day, e.g. with 12/2/2012 9:22 AM that will convert to 12/2/2012 **9**:45 - is that the required result or do you want to get the same time whatever the day?

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Barry. I understand that it will not divide exactly in to a day if we use 75mins, there will be a 15mins interval for each day. But I want the time exactly like your example instead of same roundup time for all the days. How to achieve the same in T-SQL?